# Variable not set and error 91 using in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, find

Hi I am facing an issue with VBA for `variable not set`.

```
Dim rngvar1 As Range
Set rngvar1 = ActiveWorksheet.Range("K" + CStr(strng.Row) + ":K" + _
    CStr(endrng.Row)).Find(what:=maxdate, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

I am getting valuea in `strng.Row`, `endrng.Row` and in `maxdate` also but getting '`nothing`' in `rngvar1`.

Also getting `-4163` in `LookIn:=xlValues`.

Comment: Most probably `strng` is no variable set?

Comment: You're not getting 2 errors at once, so which error is this section of code giving you now, and where?

Comment: You should post your full code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things in your code:

1. Have Error handling scenario if `Find` failed to fetch `maxdate`.
2. You are searching for a `Date`, try using `LookIn:=xlFormulas`.

The rest of my comments in the code below:

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim rngvar1 As Range

Set Sht = ActiveSheet ' <-- rather not use ActiveSheet, better use Worksheets("YourSheetName")

With Sht
    Set rngvar1 = .Range(.Cells(strng.Row, "K"), .Cells(endrng.Row, "K")).Find(what:=maxdate, LookIn:=xlFormulas)

    If Not rngvar1 Is Nothing Then ' If Find was successfull
        ' put the rest of your code here

    Else ' Find failed >> raise an error message
        MsgBox "Error finding " & maxdate, vbCritical
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

If `rngvar1` is `Nothing`, then you cannot use `.Find` for it. Thus, make a check whether it is "Not Nothing", before assigning:

```
Dim rngvar1 As Range
Set rngvar1 = ActiveWorksheet.Range("K" + CStr(strng.Row) + ":K" + CStr(endrng.Row))
If Not rngvar1 Is Nothing Then
    Set rngvar1 = rngvar1.Find(what:=maxDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
End If
```